# How can I define default imports for Stylus in nuxt.js

Tags: webpack, vue.js, stylus, webpack-2

I import various helpers (mixins, vars, functions) into my component automatically to ensure they're always available to me and my team.

Currently I use the vue-cli webpack template and to import these helpers I set the stylus import option within the webpack.base.js config as shown below;

```
stylus: { import: ['~stylus/common.styl'] }
```

I've not been able to figure out how to do this with nuxt.js, I raised an [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/148) about this and was told to use the build extend method.

This didn't work as I then received errors from webpack itself;

```
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
```

So with the changes brought in with v2.2.0 of webpack, how can I apply my stylus options?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack 2 changed the syntax slightly. Instead of having a `stylus` key in the top level Webpack config, you have an `options` key under your `stylus-loader` configuration. So you should use something like:

```
...
{
  loader: 'stylus-loader',
  options: {
    import: ['~stylus/common.styl']
  }
}
...
```

[Here's a solution](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/10/moving-to-webpack-2/#configuring-loaders) for an identical issue with a different loader.

Comment: The problem is I don't have direct access to the webpack config with nuxt.js, they offer an entry point to extend the webpack config.

It looks like I want to push a new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin on to the plugin part of the config... fingers crossed

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly thought you had direct access since you wrote _I set the stylus import option within the webpack.base.js_. But yeah, as you found out, `LoaderOptionsPlugin` is the alternative way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Sadly still doesn't work, it looks like it maybe something on stylus-loader end but i'm not too sure.

The nuxt.js guys have passed the buck so i'll have to wait and see what happens.